# How to manipulate the string in the cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have three columns in an Excel spreadsheet, First Name, Last Name, and Email

The raw data on those fields like this

**Sunny M, Jones, sunnyj@woody.com** (the first name including the middle initial on some names)

I want to replace the email address with the format like

FirstName.LastName@whatever.com

The new email address will become

**Sunny.M.Jones@whaterver.com**

How to do that using formula in a new cell?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Column A = First Name

Column B = Last Name

Column C = Email Address

The basic case will be a concatenation of the columns while only using the part to the right of the @.  For the case of the initial you will need to substitute a "." for the space.

in column D you could use the following:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",".")&B1&RIGHT(C1,LEN(C1)-FIND("@",C1))
```

In the example below I wrapped the whole thing in a LOWER() function to get all lower case for the email address.

[image: POC]

Answer (score -1):

Try This: [Check the result in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/60DcZ.png)

```
=CONCATENATE(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(CONCATENATE(A2," ",B2))," ","."),"@whatever.com")
```